# How to set use key combination that uses two letters with keydown event?

Tags: javascript

It is easy to do with a combination of Shift, Ctrl, Alt with an ordinary letter, but how can I make a key combination with two letters work?

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.altKey == true && e.key == "N"){
    //This would work
    console.log('Alt + N'); 
  }

  if(e.key == "N" && e.key == "O"){
   //This would not work
   console.log('N + O');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the pressed keys in a `Map`, setting its value to `true` on `keydown` and resetting it to `false` on `keyup`. Then, you can simply check if both keys have a value of `true` in the `Map` to determine whether or not they are both pressed down.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
const isPressed = new Map;
const handler = e=>{
  isPressed.set(e.key, e.type==='keydown');
  if(isPressed.get('n') && isPressed.get('o')){
    p.textContent = "N and O both pressed";
    p.style.color = "#7FFF00";
  } else {
    p.textContent = "Keep trying.";
    p.style.color = "red";
  }
};
["keydown", "keyup"].forEach(ev=>window.addEventListener(ev, handler));
```

```html
Focus here and press some keys. (Hint: N + O is the magic combination.)
<p></p>
```

Comment: It seems like that your example doesn't work.  I can't get "N and O both pressed"

Comment: @HugoSum Did you focus on the iframe by clicking on it? It works fine for me.